# Find element by text with XPath in ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

Given an XML like the following:

```
<root>
    <element>A</element>
    <element>B</element>
</root>
```

How can I match the element with content A using ElementTree and its support for XPath? Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

AFAIK ElementTree does not support XPath. Has it changed?

Anyway, you can use [lxml](http://lxml.de) and the following XPath expression:

```
import lxml.etree
doc = lxml.etree.parse('t.xml')
print doc.xpath('//element[text()="A"]')[0].text
print doc.xpath('//element[text()="A"]')[0].tag
```

The result will be:

```
A
element
```

Comment: ElementTree supports xpath, see my answer below.

Answer (score 12):

You can use a subset of [XPath in ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support). It isn't necessary to install any lib.

```
config.findall('.//*[element="A"]/element')
```

As the comment bellow from @Bionicegenius explains, the expression above just works if your element has no sibilings, but you get the idea.

**It is possible to use XPath in ElementTree**, and it is the simplest solution.

Comment: This has a problem of selecting all the elements on the same level as the desired node. This will find both elements with values A and B.

If you modify it to find, then it will only ever find the element with a value of A, even if you search for B - it will only return the first child.

Comment: Searching by text is a recent addition, the syntax is `.//element[.="A"]` . The above answer wouldn't work. ElementTree only support a very limited subset of XPath.

Comment: @dwery - Great, thanks! Once I knew the syntax to look for, I found it in the python docs - it says it was added in Python 3.7. It's been there long enough for me!

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use the standard library [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), rather than lxml, you can use iteration to find all sub elements with a particular text value. For example:

```
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

s = """<root>
    <element>A</element>
    <element>B</element>
</root>"""

e = etree.fromstring(s)

if sys.version_info < (2, 7):
    found = [element for element in e.getiterator() if element.text == 'A']
else:
    found = [element for element in e.iter() if element.text == 'A']

print found[0].text # This prints 'A', honestly!
```

Note: you may want to perform some stripping of the `text` value of your elements in the list comprehension.

**Edit** This will work to any depth in your XML tree. For example,

```
s = """<root>
    <element>A</element>
    <element><sub>A</sub></element>
</root>"""

found = [element for element in e.getiterator() if element.text == 'A']

for f in found:
    print f
```

will print

```
<Element element at 7f20a882e3f8>
<Element sub at 7f20a882e4d0>
```

Comment: I have chosen to use cElementTree over lxml since for my task it has a much lower memory overhead (memory being more critical than CPU usage), this was the final bit of code I needed to move from lxml

Comment: Can you please explain what "element for element" means?

Comment: @ElliottB It is part of list comprehensions.