# search entire tree with etree

Tags: python, xml

I am using xml.etree.ElementTree as ET, this seems like the go-to library but if there is something else/better for the job I'm intrigued.

Let's say I have a tree like:

```
doc = """
<top>
<second>
<third>
    <subthird></subthird>
    <subthird2>
         <subsubthird>findme</subsubthird>
    </subthird2>
</third>
</second>
</top>"""
```

and for the sake of this problem, let's say this is already in an elementree named `myTree`

I want to update `findme` to `found`, is there a simple way to do it other than iterating like:

```
myTree.getroot().getchildren()[0].getchildren()[0].getchildren() \
    [1].getchildren()[0].text = 'found'
```

The issue is I have a large xml tree and I want to update these values and I can't find a clear and pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XPath expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) to get a specific tagname like this:

```
for el in myTree.getroot().findall(".//subsubthird"):
    el.text = 'found'
```

If you need to find all tags with a specific text value, take a look at this answer: [Find element by text with XPath in ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836205/find-element-by-text-with-xpath-in-elementtree).

Answer (score 0):

I use `lxml` with XPath expressions. `ElementTree` has an abbreviated XPath syntax but since I don't use it, I don't know how extensive it is. The thing about XPath is that you can write as complex an element selector as you need. In this example, its based on nesting:

```
import lxml.etree 

doc = """
<top>
<second>
<third>
    <subthird></subthird>
    <subthird2>
         <subsubthird>findme</subsubthird>
    </subthird2>
</third>
</second>
</top>"""

root = lxml.etree.XML(doc)
for elem in root.xpath('second/third/subthird2/subsubthird'):
    elem.text = 'found'

print(lxml.etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, encoding='unicode'))
```

But suppose there was something else identifying, such as a unique attribute,

```
<subthird2 class="foo"><subsubthird>findme</subsubthird></subthird2>
```

then you xpath would be `//subthird2[@class="foo"]/subsubthird`.