# xml.etree.elementtree return subelement by its text

Tags: xml, python-3.5

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
xm = xml.fromstring('<element attribute="value">text<subelement subattribute="subvalue">subtext</subelement></element>')
subelement = xml.findtext("subtext")
```

isn't working. I already tried to so many things:

```
>>> xm. xm.__class__(       xm.__copy__(        xm.__deepcopy__(        xm.__delattr__(     xm.__delitem__(     xm.__dir__(     xm.__doc__      xm.__eq__(      xm.__format__(      xm.__ge__(      xm.__getattribute__(        xm.__getitem__(     xm.__getstate__(        xm.__gt__(      xm.__hash__(        xm.__init__(        xm.__le__(      xm.__len__(     xm.__lt__(      xm.__ne__(      xm.__new__(     xm.__reduce__(      xm.__reduce_ex__(       xm.__repr__(        xm.__setattr__(     xm.__setitem__(     xm.__setstate__(        xm.__sizeof__(      xm.__str__(     xm.__subclasshook__(        xm.append(      xm.clear(       xm.extend(      xm.find(        xm.findall(     xm.findtext(        xm.get(     xm.getchildren(     xm.getiterator(     xm.insert(      xm.items(       xm.iter(        xm.iterfind(        xm.itertext(        xm.keys(        xm.makeelement(     xm.remove(      xm.set(
```

The only thing that seems to work is

```
>>> xm.getchildren()    

[<Element 'subelement' at 0x0000029B288AD958>]
```

which does not seem to be the optimal way :c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find element by text with XPath in ElementTree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836205/find-element-by-text-with-xpath-in-elementtree)

Comment: Why would it be that complicated? And what are etree's functions for then?

Comment: .findtext(), according to the documentation, finds that text in the element name. (It may be a badly named method).

Comment: what about etree's .get() and .find() ?