# lxml invalid predicate when using text()

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'm using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) to do HTML screen scraping and I need to select an element by `text()`, in a similar way to [what is done on another question with pure XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836343/57626), however no matter what happens I'm getting invalid predicate errors. I've simplified it down to this example:

```
import lxml.html
sample_html = "<div><h2>test string</h2><h2>other string</h2></div>"
sample_tree = lxml.html.fromstring(sample_html)
sample_tree.findall('.//h2[text()="test string"]')
```

While this should be valid, I continually get the error:

```
  File "<string>", line unknown
SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

Any hints on how to properly get lxml to select an element by `text()` when parsing HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *expression itself is valid*, but you have to use the `.xpath()` method instead:

```
sample_tree.xpath('.//h2[text()="text string"]')
```

Note that you may also use [`.` in place of `text()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240763/xpath-difference-between-dot-and-text) in this case:

```
.//h2[. = "text string"]
```