# ElementTree find index of SubElement

Tags: python, xml, plist, elementtree

I am trying to use python to edit .plist files, which are in XML format.  In this example, I want to modify the IP address.

```
<dict>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/ExD2017/render/bin/renderqueue</string>
        <string>-h</string>
        <string>127.0.0.1</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

In this case, I can get the value by using `root[1][2].text`, but this will break if the argument order in the XML changes.  So I need to find it by specifying the tag following the tag named string whose value is `-h`.  How can I find the index of the string whose value is `-h`?  It should be a nested number like `root[x][x]`.

Comment: You want to look at XPath (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support). In 99% of all cases trying to use numeric indexes with XML trees is the wrong thing to do. This is one of those cases.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know how to do this with XPath?  According to the online XPath tester, this code should work, but it gives a syntax error in my script. `root.findall("./dict/array/string[.='-h']")`

Comment: Hm, the XPath implementation of elementtree is very lackluster. `./dict/array[string='-h']` ("finding an element by the text value of one of its children") would work, `./dict/array/string[.='-h']` ("finding an element by its own text value") is not supported. Also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10836205/18771). Do you have lxml installed by any chance, things would be much more straight-forward there: `tree.xpath("./dict/array/string[preceding-sibling::string[1]='-h']")` would get you precisely the right element.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to iterate through all children anyway, to find `-h`, you can you can simply iterate to the next child:

```
h_found = False
for child in array_element:
    if child.text == '-h':
        h_found = True
    elif h_found:
        child.text = new_ip
        break
```